# Infinite conversion loop when using custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my current project I have the problem that I end up in an infinite loop when trying to convert an `Item` or any of its subclasses like `ArmorItem`.
To detect which type of `Item` I have to deserialize I use a custom `JsonConverter` called `ItemConverter`.

Item.cs:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn), JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverter))]
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")] public int Id { get; }
    [JsonProperty("type")] public string ItemType { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Item(int id, string itemType)
    {
        Id = id;
        ItemType = itemType;
    }
}
```

ArmorItem.cs

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public sealed class ArmorItem : Item
{
    [JsonProperty("defense")] public int Defense { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ArmorItem(int id, string itemType, int defense) : base(id, itemType)
    {
        Defense = defense;
    }
}
```

ItemConverter.cs

```
public sealed class ItemConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);

        switch (item["type"].Value<string>())
        {
            case "Armor":
                return item.ToObject<ArmorItem>();
            default:
                return item.ToObject<Item>();
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => typeof (Item).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
}
```

I'm usually getting the json data from the web and directly use the `WebResponse.GetResponseStream` stream to deserialize the data.

```
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())))
{
    return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<Item>(reader);
}
```

I know why this loop occurs but I can't fix it.
However I noticed when deserializing the json data in a different way the problem doesn't occur.
(`Item` was altered for this by removing the `JsonConverter` attribute)

```
string json = "SOME JSON DATA HERE";
Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json, new ItemConverter());
```

Unfortunately I cannot fix the existing code using streams and I don't want to temporarily store the incoming json data into a string to be able to use the working code.
Any ideas how to break the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to tell Json.net to deserialize your json via standard converter, not your custom one. While there's more than one way to do it, this is the one I can offer right now:

1. Remove `JsonConverter(typeof(ItemConverter))` from `Item`. This will allow `item.ToObject<Item>()` to work properly.
2. Now you need to tell your *outer* deserialization to use the converter. To do that:

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
   {
     Converters = new [] { new ItemConverter() }
   };
   return JsonSerializer.Create(settings).Deserialize<Item>(reader)
   ```

   (actually, you can cache the settings)

Comment: I actually don't like this solution as it is cleaner to annotate the class with the attribute.
Creating boilerplate serialization code to run on every async call to a service (since Newtonsoft.Json is used in HttpClient) is a bit ugly. It should be able to be handled gracefully within the custom converter. If this is not possible then there is a hole in the framework which would be nice to fill

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use `serializer.Populate()`:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);

    switch (item["type"].Value<string>())
    {
        case "Armor":
            var armorItem = new ArmorItem();
            serializer.Populate(item.CreateReader(), armorItem);
            return armorItem;
        default:
            var defaultItem = new Item();
            serializer.Populate(item.CreateReader(), defaultItem);
            return defaultItem;
    }
}
```

More infos at https://gist.github.com/chrisoldwood/b604d69543a5fe5896a94409058c7a95

Comment: Using `serializer.Populate()` with a new class instance instead of using `item.ToObject<T>()` solved the infinite loop/stack overflow problem when using the `JsonConverter` attribute.

Comment: Any tips on how to get the derived classes' props to populate too?   Like, if Armor had a couple unique things.